# slideshow images for one specific view, with alot of fields

Tags: views, 6, javascript

I have a product content type which has like 10 fields, so I want to show it in my main page with view, the problem is, I want to show it's multiple images as a slideshow, It's not only images that I can use views_slideshow or nivo_slider or any other slideshow modules, I only want the images to be shown as slideshow, along other text-fields of my node.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow). If it's not a good solution, another one would be to create 2 views (one slideshow with only the images, one normal with all the other fields) and, with CSS, position one over the other.

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks Greg, Field slideshow would do the trick, just need to test it, thanks again

Comment: I just saw that your post was in Drupal 6 ; but the module is only Drupal 7... :(

Comment: oh crap, yea i didnt notice that

Comment: Then I guess you have to create the two views as I described it :-)